# Python pandas plot TypeError

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a data frame that looks like:

```
         CreateDate                Store       Orders_am        Orders_pm
0       2018-01-21                  2001           56               2
1       2018-01-21                  2002           51               4
2       2018-01-21                  2003           85               0
```

dtypes for the data frame are:

```
CreateDate        datetime64[ns]
Store             int64
Orders_am         int64
Orders_pm         int64
```

I'm trying to create a simple plot using the following:

```
plt.plot(df.groupby("Store").plot(x="CreateDate", y="Orders_am"))
```

But it's throwing the following error:

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'AxesSubplot'
```

I'm assuming that it's choking on CreateDate - but I can't figure out how to solve it.

Comment: remove plt.plot()

Comment: df.pivot(index='CreateDate',columns='Store',values='Orders_am').plot(kind='bar')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pandas` is more than just a library to make some good formatting. This is also a wrapper for `matplotlib`. `pandas` is, in other words, a higher level of abstraction for `matplotlib`. Doing `df.groupby("Store").plot(x="CreateDate", y="Orders_am")` should be enough.

However, if you would have wanted to use `plt.plot()`, you could have done it like any other plot, and specify the Xs and Ys into the function, such as, for instance...

```
store = df.groupby("Store")
plt.plot(store['CreateDate'], store['Orders_am'])
```

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation! This solved it.